# I need to filter the list based on the user input in scala list

Tags: scala

How to get the result as like below?

```
val original=List("a","ab","abc","abcd","zadad","ji","jijdf","bcab", "frab","abkcdef","opabcd")
val find="ab"
val result="abc","abcd","bcab","frab","abcdef","opabcd"
```

Comment: what did you try? show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` to check which elements of the original List contains the find element:

```
original.filter(_.contains(find))
```

**EDIT**:

To skip elements that are equals:

```
original.filter(elem => elem.contains(find) && !elem.equals(find) )
```

**Result**:

```
List[String] = List(abc, abcd, bcab, frab, abkcdef, opabcd)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
original.filter(_.contains(find))
```

should do the trick. filter lets you apply a predicate, so a function from element type to boolean

Comment: Your code result in additional "ab" in final list. How can you add check if elements on list are not equal to find?

Comment: You can add a condition to skip equality: original.filter(elem => elem.contains(find) && !elem.equals(find) )

Comment: I was hoping for some more elegant/shorter solution.